# Is there really no way to prevent Invoke-WebRequest from following redirections

Tags: powershell

It seems the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet provides no way to inspect redirecting responses (by saying "don't follow redirections"). This would make the `curl`-alias not only ridiculous but even more than superfluous.

Can anybody spare me this disappointment?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the `MaximumRedirection` parameter to prevent implicit redirects from occuring:

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://www.google.com -MaximumRedirection 0
```

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked it. Shame on me!